# Server is Trying to Convert Repeater Control Inside HTML Table to HtmlTableRow

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net, vb.net, webforms

I have used the following code successfully in two other pages:

```
<table id="TBL_Tracks" runat="server" class="table table-striped table-responsive" data-paging="true" data-page-size="10" data-sorting="true" data-filtering="true">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th data-field="TrackID" data-type="number">ID</th>
            <th data-field="TrackName">Name</th>
            <th data-field="TrackLength">Length</th>
            <th data-field="TrackNumber" data-type="number"># in Album</th>
            <th data-field="Album.AlbumName">Album</th>
            <th data-field="Album.Band.BandName">Band</th>
            <th data-sortable="false">&nbsp;</th>
            <th data-sortable="false">&nbsp;</th>
            <th data-sortable="false">&nbsp;</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <asp:Repeater ID="REP_Tracks" runat="server">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <asp:Label ID="LBL_TrackID" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("TrackID") %>' />
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:Label ID="TrackName" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("TrackName") %>' CssClass="text-primary font-weight-bold" />
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:Label ID="LBL_TrackLength" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("TrackLength") %>' />
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:Label ID="LBL_TrackNumber" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("TrackNumber") %>' />
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:Label ID="LBL_AlbumName" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("Album.AlbumName") %>' />
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:Label ID="LBL_BandName" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("Album.Band.BandName") %>' />
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:Button ID="BTN_Details" runat="server" CssClass="btn btn-block btn-lg btn-info" Text="Details" CommandName="Details" UseSubmitBehavior="false" />
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:Button ID="BTN_Edit" runat="server" CssClass="btn btn-block btn-lg btn-warning" Text="Edit" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#EditTrack" CommandName="Edit" UseSubmitBehavior="false" />
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:Button ID="BTN_Delete" runat="server" CssClass="btn btn-block btn-lg btn-danger" Text="Delete" CommandName="Delete" UseSubmitBehavior="false" />
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:Repeater>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

But instead of getting a nice sortable, filterable, and paged table using FooTable.js, I get this error:

```
Compilation Error
Description: An error occurred during the compilation of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific error details and modify your source code appropriately. 

Compiler Error Message: BC30311: Value of type 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.Repeater' cannot be converted to 'System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlTableRow'.
```

I also know this code works because I tried using an inline code block, but my Delete, Details, and Edit buttons needed a NamingContainer to function properly. You can read the Q&A [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57279783/getting-html-table-rows-in-vb-net). I have used date formatting, numbers, and strings easily in the previous pages; the only thing different about this one is it uses a TimeSpan for the track length - `Public Property TrackLength As TimeSpan`. I honestly don't think the problem is with the repeater control; I think the page is very, very confused some other way, and that has confused me. :D

Answer (score 1):

As it turns out, it's a bad idea to add `runat="server"` to tables if you want to use a Repeater inside them. Once I took that off, everything worked great!